# View Model Constructor Arguments

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc

I have created a ViewModel for a Product Edit page because it has specific related entities I need to load - the class currently looks like this:

```
public class ProductEditView
{
    public ProductEditView(Product product)
    {
        this.ID = product.ID;
        this.Code = product.Code;
        this.ProductLanguage = product.ProductLanguages.Where(x => x.LanguageID == Global.Language).FirstOrDefault();
        this.PrimaProduct = product.PrimaProduct;
        this.Multimedias = product.Multimedias;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public ProductLanguage ProductLanguage { get; set; }
    public PrimaProduct PrimaProduct { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Multimedia> Multimedias { get; set; }

}
```

So then in my controller I can go:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null) return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
    if (product == null) return HttpNotFound();

    ProductEditView productEditView = new ProductEditView(product);
    return View(productEditView);
}
```

I've not really seen anybody do it like this though, is it bad practice - and for what reason? What are the better alternatives to accomplish this if this is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Its a very tight coupling between HTTP and your domain.
However I do not like classic layered architecture. I often utilizes CQS for my service API's

Your example would look like

```
public class GetProductQueryHandler: IQueryHandler<GetProductQuery, Product>
{
   private readonly DbContext db;

   public GetProductQueryHandler(DbContext db) {
      this.db = db;
   }    
   public async Task<Product> Handle(GetProductQuerycommand query) {
      if (!query.Id.HasValue) throw new ArgumentExpection("Id is required"); //Not accepting null for a Nullable is a bit strange

      var product = await db.Products.FindAsync(id);
      if (product == null) throw new NotFoundExcpetion("Product");

      return product;
   }
}
```

You can then translate the errors into HTTP codes using a Exception filter, here is an example from my current project

```
    public class ExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute 
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);

            var message = "Server error";
            var details = "Please contact support if the problem persists";

            var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

            if(actionExecutedContext.Exception is ArgumentException)
            {
                code = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                message = "Bad Arguments";
                details = actionExecutedContext.Exception.Message;
            }

#if DEBUG
    details =   string.Format("{0}: {1}", actionExecutedContext.Exception.Message, actionExecutedContext.Exception.StackTrace);
#endif

            var response = new
            {
                Message = message,
                Details = details
            };

            actionExecutedContext.Response = actionExecutedContext.Request.CreateResponse(code, response);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing it at the moment is fine, though it creates a bond between `Product` and `ProductEditView`.

I'd consider your constructor more like an helper method than a necessity, considering all the properties are `public get/set` (which is very good in the case of a view).

You just need to consider if `ProductEditView` could ever be built from information that wouldn't arrive from a `Product`. Now, I've typed this sentence and realized it makes no sense :p

Your way is fine.

Instead of `.Where(x => x.LanguageID == Global.Language).FirstOrDefault();` you should use `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LanguageID == Global.Language)` which has the same behavior but it's clearer! :)

Also, in a case like this : `ProductEditView productEditView = new ProductEditView(product);` Consider using `var` instead of `ProductEditView`, it shortens the code and it is okay to use `var` in such a case because you can see what is the type of `productEditView` just by looking at the code.